# Remove decimals fom pandas column(String type)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to remove decimal points from a pandas column Which is of string type

Df

```
Net Sales
123.45
34.89
65.00
```

I am trying to remove decimals from that column

```
Net Sales
123
34
65
```

df['Net Sales'] is already a string type.

I tried as below:

`df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)`

But I get teh error as below:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1567.55'`

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If values are strings first convert to floats and then to integers:

```
df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].astype(float).astype(int)
```

If values are floats use:

```
df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].astype(int)
```

Your solution should be changed with `\d+` for match digits after `.`:

```
df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].astype(str).replace('\.\d+', '', regex=True).astype(int)
print (df)
   Net Sales
0        123
1         34
2         65
```

Or youcan use `split` by dot and select first list by indexing:

```
df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0].astype(int)
```

Comment: Are we thinking on similar lines...we are :)

Comment: @PKumar - yop, difference is in `$`

Answer (score 3):

You can coerce the datatype to int, Just a note in case you have nans in your data, the conversion to int doesn't work as they have float data type, so regex solution might be better.

```
df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].astype('int')
```

or in case of **regex**:

```
df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].astype('str').replace(r'\.\d+$', '', regex=True).astype('int')
```

**Example**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Net Sales" : [1.5, 2.5]})

df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].astype('int')

df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].astype('str').replace(r'\.\d+$', '', regex=True).astype('int')
```

**Output:**

```
#   Net Sales
#0  1
#1  2
```